# Nuxt Server Side Fetch & Internal Links Best Practices

Tags: javascript, frontend, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, nuxt-link

I would like to fetch data always server side (in order to prevent them can be read from network tab)

When the page is refreshed (or first time loaded) `process.server` returns `true` and nothing can be seen on network tab.

```
  async asyncData({ params, $axios }) {
    console.log(process.server)
    const { id } = params;
    const url = `api/post/${params.id}`
    const post = await $axios.$get(url);
    return { post };
  }
```

However when I tried to navigate via internal link by using `router-link` or `nuxt-link` always end up with client side fetch. `process.server` returns `false` and request/response can be seen on network tab.

The only solution that I came up with using `<a>` instead internal links, thanks to this page is loaded and we can fetch server side.

Nuxt docs says always use `nuxt-link` instead `<a>` for the internal links but `<a>` can be used for external links. So I was wondering what the downside(s) is if we use for internal links (just in order to refresh page and make sure fetching on server side)

Or is there any better way to fetch always server side when we navigate?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I handle it and use `nuxt-link`'s throughout.

Use the [`fetch`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/components-glossary/fetch/) hook then it's called on both.

```
async fetch() {
  this.getItems()
},
```

Additionally, if you wanted you can directly call serverside code through `this.$root.context.ssrContext`, which would be the same kind of thing you do if you use [nuxtServerInit](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/store#the-nuxtserverinit-action) in stores.

```
async fetch() {
  if (process.server) {
    let items = []
    if (this.isset(this.$root, 'context.ssrContext.req.thingsModel')) {
      items = this.$root.context.ssrContext.req.cache.get('things', [])
      if (!items.length) {
        items = await this.$root.context.ssrContext.req.thingsModel.get(
          this.limit
        )
        items = this.$copy(items)
        this.$root.context.ssrContext.req.cache.put('things', items, 60000 * 60)
      }
    }

    this.items = items
  } else {
    this.getItems() // would be an ajax call to populate items
  }
},
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't follow. Even we use fetch, the first line "process.server" always return false (assuming we clicked the internal nuxt-link) and it will send request from client, right?

Comment: `ssr` / `process.server` only happens on direct hit or page refresh, when you click on a nuxt-link its always client-side rendered

Comment: Yes exactly what I am trying to sort this out. I would like to make every calls in server side to keep it more private. The only way that I can think of using <a> tag instead nuxt-link but since nuxt docs doesn't recommend this for the internal links